# Spark Streaming from Kafka not producing output on console

Tags: spark-streaming, kafka-producer-api

I have below code which will listen to a kafka topic and reproduce the text as-is using spark streaming. However, I am unable to see the text on the console. I am not getting any ERROR message on the console. I could be wrong but I expect the text from kafka topic to be displayed on console.

```
object scalaSparkProcessor {
 def main(args: Array[String]) {
  if (args.length < 3) {
     System.err.println("Usage: scalaSparkProcessor <zkQuorum> topics> <numThreads>")
     System.exit(1)
  }

  val Array(zkQuorum, topics, numThreads) = args
  val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("scalaSparkProcessor")
  val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(5))
  ssc.checkpoint("checkpoint")

  val topicMap = topics.split(",").map((_, numThreads.toInt)).toMap

  val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc,zkQuorum,"spark-streaming-consumer", topicMap).map(_._2)

  lines.foreachRDD{rdd =>
  rdd.foreach { println }}     

  ssc.start()
  ssc.awaitTermination()
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the `println` code runs on the executor, so you should see the output in the executors console output.
So, if you go to the spark UI, navigate to the executors tab, and choose an executor, you should be able to see the output there.

E.g. if you're running the job locally, you can go to go to http://localhost:4040.
If you're running on yarn, you can navigate to the spark UI through the yarn ResourceManager UI.

Answer (score 0):

make the following adjustment in your code:

```
lines.foreachRDD{
 rdd =>
  rdd.collect().foreach(println)
 }
```